# How to validate a hidden field

Tags: validation

I'm using the bootstrapValidator plugin and have a hidden field whose value is set dynamically. When the user makes choices which get added to the hidden field the validation is not picking it up.

Here is the field I'm trying to validate
customerVehicles
HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label  class="" for="fname"></label>   
  <input type="hidden" name="customerVehicles" class="customerVehicles form-control"  id="customerVehicles"   />   
</div><!-- close form group -->
```

Here is my validation block
Code:

```
$('#step2').bootstrapValidator({
   message: 'This value is not valid',
   live: 'enabled',
   feedbackIcons: {
   valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
   invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
   validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
  },
  submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {

  document.getElementById("next2").disabled=true;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripts/process-step2.php",
    data: $('#step2').serialize(),
    success: function(msg){

           ...
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("error");
    }
   });//close ajax
  },
  excluded: ':disabled',
  fields: {

      customerVehicles: {
          message: 'Please Make a Selection',
          validators: {
          notEmpty: {
              message: 'Please Make a Selection'
          }    
        }
      }// end dropdown
   } // end field
});// bootstrapValidator
```

Comment: anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this worked for me. The excluded option looks to be an array of states.  Try:

`excluded: [':disabled']`